# How to access array sending from controller to ajax success?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

as i am new to codeigniter and ajax please can any one do favor for me.I am sending array from my controller to ajax function but how can i access that array element.I am posting here my code.
Thanks in advance.

```
public function index()
{
    $Modules = $this->General_model->AllMoudules();
    $data['result'] = $this->printTree($Modules);
    $output = array(
    'html'=>$this->load->view("Add_user",$data),
    'data' => $data
    );
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

and ajax function

```
$("#user").on("click",function(){      
var url=static_url+'/User';
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:url,

        success:function(output)
        {
           $(output).each( function (index, o) {
           alert (o.data);

         });
        }

  });
```

});

Comment: And what isn't working?  When you use your browser's debugging tools, what is the value of `output` in the success function?

Comment: just check first your output by; console.log(output). in console by inspecting element. Then you can understand this easily how to function on data.

Comment: you can also put die('hello'); in controller for checking that this is calling or not.

Comment: thanks for reply as you say to check console.log(output) i did that whole html code is appearing in it because i am sending it in array named output but i want to access first array element and second array element seperatly

Comment: add `header('Content-type: application/json')` to your controller's method.

Answer (score 2):

**controller:**

```
  public function index()
        {
            $Modules = $this->General_model->AllMoudules();
            $data['result'] = $this->printTree($Modules);
            $output = array(
            'html'=>$this->load->view("Add_user",$data,true),
            'data' => $data
            );
            echo json_encode($output);
        }

**Javascript:**

$("#user").on("click",function(){      
var url=static_url+'/User';
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:url,

        success:function(output)
        {
          console.log(output.data);
          console.log(output.html);

         });
        }

  });
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

To load view in the string you have add third parameter to load view as below:

```
$output = array(
    'html'=>$this->load->view("Add_user", $data, true),
    'data' => $data
);
```

To access your ajax response try the below code

```
success:function(output)
{
    console.log(output.html);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just get the length of array using array.length.
Then for loop it

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax datatype as json like this

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.key);
        }
    });
```